# How to solve *builder.code.codershub.org uses an unsupported protocol. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH*?

Tags: ssl, subdomain, cloudflare

I'm currently designing and developing my [website](https://www.codershub.org/)

And today I have created subdomain of subdomain [builder.code.codershub.org](https://builder.code.codershub.org) but it's showing error:

> "builder.code.codershub.org uses an unsupported protocol.
>   ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH".

I'm using GoDaddy ECONOMY hosting and cloudflare SSL, I think there is problem with SSL but I don't know how to solve it. When I try to access with HTTP its working and with HTTPS its not working. And I also cant make a  directory for it because my web app will not support it. Please help me out.

Comment: `builder.code.codershub.org` does not seem configured to accept HTTPS connections

Comment: but how can I do that?